# Constant Flask Session IDs

Tags: python, session, flask, session-cookies, sessionid

I've a `Flask` application, served with Nginx+WSGI (FastCGI & Gevent) and use standard Flask sessions. I do *not* use the `session.permanent=True` or any other extra option, but simply set `SECRET_KEY` in the default configuration.

I do *not* save any (key,value) pairs in the session, and only rely on the `SID = session['_id']` entry to identify a returning user. I use the following code the read the `SID`:

```
@page.route ('/')
def main (page='home', template='index.html'):

    if not request.args.get ('silent', False):
        print >> sys.stderr, "Session ID: %r" % session['_id']
```

I made the following observations:

1. For same IP addresses, but different browsers I get different `SIDs` - that's expected;
2. For different IPs & same browser I again have different `SIDs` - expected;
3. For same IP address with same browser I get same `SID` - also expected;

Now, point (3) is interesting because even if a *delete* the corresponding cookie the `SID` remains **constant**! To some extent even that might be understandable, but actually I was expecting the `SID` to change between different cookies. But the only difference I see is that

```
session.new is True
```

for the *first* request immediately after the deletion of the cookie. Even that is very much expected; but given these facts I face the following problems:

1. Does this mean that for *different* users sitting behind the *same* IP (with the same browser configuration) my back-end will mistake them for the *same* user?
2. If point (1) is *not* the case, the current behavior of these "sticky" sessions is actually quite pleasant, since this avoids the situation where my users might loose there data just because they deleted the corresponding cookie.

   They can still save the day, by revisiting the site from the same network with the same browser. I like that, but only *if* point (1) is *not* the case.
3. I assume point (1) will actually bite me, would the conclusion actually be to save a `token` in the session and hence accept the fate that the user can blow himself up, by simply deleting his cookie?
4. Or is there a way to tell `Flask` to give different `SIDs` for each fresh cookie?

Actually, this question arouse since I used a load impact service, which was simulating *different* users (on the same IP) but my back-end kept seeing them as a single user since the corresponding `SIDs` were all the same.

The application is available for tests at http://webed.blackhan.ch (which upon release will move the **https://notex.ch** [a browser based text editor]). Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Flask-Login extension. Here's the code that generates the id token:

```
def _create_identifier():
    base = unicode("%s|%s" % (request.remote_addr,
                              request.headers.get("User-Agent")), 'utf8', errors='replace')
    hsh = md5()
    hsh.update(base.encode("utf8"))
    return hsh.digest()
```

It's basically just `md5(ip_address + user_agent)`.

Flask uses [Werkzeug's secure cookies](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/contrib/securecookie/) to store this identifier. Secure cookies are (as their name suggests) secure:

> This module implements a cookie that is not alterable from the client because it adds a checksum the server checks for. You can use it as session replacement if all you have is a user id or something to mark a logged in user.

Comment: Thank you for the answer: Indeed I'm using `Flask-Login` and I guess this explains why I was seeing only a single user with same (IP, User-Agent) combination. I've introduced a token in the cookie to be able to distinguish in this case.

Comment: @hsk81: That's odd. I'm pretty sure Flask's sessions are assigned random IDs as well to prevent problems like this

Comment: No idea, it keeps giving me a constant value for `session['_id']` even after deleting the cookie. My impression is, that there is no such randomization, or somehow `session['_id']` is the wrong way to access a session's identity. I haven't found a reference about what the *canonical* approach here should be, and just looked in the cookie what entry Flask creates and used that: `'_id'`. I might have maybe overlooked something in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`session['_id']` is not an actual session identifier. It's just a value used by Flask-Login to implement [Session Protection](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#session-protection).

*Standard* Flask sessions do not have an SID - as it would serve no purpose since the actual content of the session is stored in the cookie itself. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156132/flask-how-to-get-session-id).

Answer (score 0):

it's now **2022**, and Flask-Session does support `session.sid` to get a generated UUID that looks something like this:

```
print(session.sid)
>>> f9c792fa-70e0-46e3-b84a-3a11813468ce
```

From [the docs](https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> **sid**
>
> Session id, internally we use uuid.uuid4() to generate one session id. You can access it with session.sid.