# Flask-Login - How to get Session ID

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Am doing a project with Flask, Gevent and web socket using flask development server environment. I used `flask_login`. Here

1. how can get i get the Unique Session ID for each connection?
2. I want to store the `SessionID` in the Database and delete it once client disconnects.
3. How to get total active connections

   ```
   from flask_login import * 
   login_manager = LoginManager()
   login_manager.setup_app(app)

   @app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"]) 
   def login():
       login_user([username], remember):    

   @app.route("/logout") 
   @login_required 
   def logout(): 
       logout_user()
   ```

Comment: You want a session id for each _connection_ or each _logged in user_?

Comment: hi Burhan, I need for each logged In User. Thanks in advance brother.

Comment: How did you use `flask_login`? Post that part of your code.

Comment: Add the code to the question, not in the comment please.

Answer (score 29):

There is no session id.

Sessions in Flask are simply wrappers over cookies. What you save on it is digitally signed and sent as a cookie to the client. When you make a request, that cookie is sent to your server and then verified and transformed into a Python object.

AFAIK, Flask-Login saves on the session the user ID.

To get total active connections, you can:

1. At login, generate an unique id and save it on the session (`flask.session['uid'] = uuid.uuid4()`, for example), then save it on your database.
2. At logout, delete that unique id from the session (`del flask.session['uid']`) and also from your database.
3. Retrieve the count of active sessions using your favourite method (ORM/Raw SQL)

Comment: Session id is the content of the cookie and you can get it from session.sid

Answer (score 0):

The session id is in:
    flask.session['_id']

Comment: `flask.session['_id']` is used by Flask-Login to implement [Session Protection](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#session-protection). "Standard" Flask sessions do not have an SID.

Answer (score 0):

As gioi explained, the session id is only the user id inside a signed cookie.
This makes it really tricky to perform what your second question says (invalidating a session)

As an alternative to gioi's answer (but pretty similar), you can also replace Flask's Session implementation with one of your own, as explained in Flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#session-interface).

This way, you could make a server-side implementation of Flask's Session and directly save the session id in the database.

Your implementation could generate a random session id cookie for each user which is associated with a user in your database (the database stores the session data, therefore it is a server-side implementation), and, through an ORM approach, Flask-Login would get the user id from there. There's also a [config file](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/src/flask_login/config.py) which allows you to change from which attribute to get the user id, in case your column doesn't have the same name.

As an easier approach, you can also have a look at [Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which already implements some of this server-side sessions.

Another option (but a bit hacky to my way of thinking) would be using Flask's [`request_loader`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader) callback instead of the traditional [`user_loader`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) callback to load the Session ID. You could then create your own cookie to store the session ID and Flask-Login would retrieve it from there with the request_loader callback.