# python/flask find unique ids for each website visitor

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask program which is storing the same information from multiple device inputs. Is there an easy way to find an ID string which is unique for each user that visits my website?

Comment: [Flask - How to get Session ID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187430/4562156) and 
[Python Flask: keeping track of user sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32643135/4562156)

Comment: I think I will re-formulate this question and post again. Why do I need to make a cookie? Why is a session variable so simple in PHP?

Comment: Flask's built-in sessions are wrappers around cookies. Any implementation which is supported in PHP likely has some similar implementation in Flask.