# If a user deletes his cookies for a Flask site, can the server still associate him with his session?

Tags: session, flask, session-cookies, flask-login

If a user deletes his cookies for a Flask site, does that effectively end that session? If not, is there any possible way that Flask could determine who the user is *without* the user signing in, so that the server can connect that user with his previous session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be "Yes, Flask can sometimes 'figure out who you are' (re-associate you with your previous session) even if you delete your cookie".

This is because your Flask-Login session ID is generated from a deterministic algorithm based solely on your IP address and `user_agent` string.

I learned all this from reading the SO question linked below and its answers:

[Constant Flask Session IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849188/constant-flask-session-ids)

> I made the following observations:
>
> 1. For same IP addresses, but different browsers I get different `SIDs` - that's expected;
> 2. For different IPs & same browser I again have different `SIDs` - expected;
> 3. **For same IP address with same browser I get same `SID`** - also expected;
>
> Now, point (3) is interesting because **even if I *delete* the**
>   **corresponding cookie the `SID` remains *constant***! To some extent
>   even that might be understandable, but actually I was expecting the
>   `SID` to change between different cookies. But the only difference I
>   see is that
>
> ```
> session.new is True
> ```
>
> for the *first* request immediately after the deletion of the cookie.

[An answer to the same question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849412/4115031)

> It looks like you're using the Flask-Login extension. Here's the code
>   that generates the id token:
>
> ```
> def _create_identifier():
>     base = unicode("%s|%s" % (request.remote_addr,
>                               request.headers.get("User-Agent")), 'utf8', errors='replace')
>     hsh = md5()
>     hsh.update(base.encode("utf8"))
>     return hsh.digest()
> ```
>
> **It's basically just `md5(ip_address + user_agent)`.**

Answer (score -1):

Session is more like unique id posted to you browser and ... So most of the time, when you change session(not session id), you just modify backend part

Comment: Right, but if the user deletes the session ID and sends a new GET request, is there any way for the server to somehow figure out who that user was and reconnect them with their existing session? That's the behavior I'm experiencing.